# Change to a newline every 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have 10 buttons in total, how can I move to a newline for every 2 buttons:

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-controller="SimpleArrayCtrl">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label ng-repeat="fruitName in fruits" class="checkbox-inline">
         <input type="checkbox" 
                name="selectedFruits[]" 
                value =  {{fruitName}}"          
                ng-checked="selection.indexOf(fruitName) > -1"  
                ng-click="toggleSelection(fruitName)"
          > {{fruitName}}
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
(function (app) {
 'use strict';

app.controller('SimpleArrayCtrl', 
               ['$scope', function   SimpleArrayCtrl($scope) {
// fruits
$scope.fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'c', 'd','e','f','g','h','i','j'];

// selected fruits
$scope.selection = [];

// toggle selection for a given fruit by name
    $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(fruitName) {
      var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(fruitName);

      // is currently selected
      if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
      }
      // is newly selected
      else {
        $scope.selection.push(fruitName);
      }
    };
  }]);
})(angular.module('app', []));
```

https://jsbin.com/goqekewalu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: you can probably do this just with css, set the style for `checkbox-inline` to be 50% wide?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with css, either by inline-blocks, or floats. An example for doing this with floats can be adding this style to your css file:

```
.form-group label.checkbox-inline {
  padding-left: 40px;
  margin-left: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Live demo: https://jsbin.com/qawoqagebu/1/edit?html,css,js,output